# write a pandas df to mysql table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

My goal is to insert an entire df into a SQL table (already created, currently empty.)
I have tried SQlAlchemy and the speed is super slow. Even just for 4500 rows. Given that to_sql arg flavor is deprecated is there any other way to perform the same?

When I try to interrupt the kernel I am unable to do so and in the end, I just close my notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the speed as I had opened multiple connections and none of them was closed. As soon as I *closed the connections* and kept just the ones in which I had to push the data. It took seconds and the data was successfully pushed into the table.